# Is it possible to effectively create a time tree graph structures?

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible to create a time tree graph strucutes in ArangoDB? For our CRM system we would like to join all relevant documents to particular date/time tree graph structure. It should be similar to technique described here
http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html .

Basicly we would like to create Year -> Month -> Day structure and join every document to particular day based on the last document modification date.

I have 2 questions here:

- Will this be performant enough for milions of documents?
- how can I effectively create a AOL query to sort the result for all 'january + februray' items by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. I worked on the creation of a Ruby Gem for ArangoDB and  one of the examples is the creation of a similar tree.

Here the link to that example.
Creation: https://github.com/StefanoMartin/ArangoRB/blob/replication_and_sharding/examples/year.rb

Retrieving: https://github.com/StefanoMartin/ArangoRB/blob/replication_and_sharding/examples/year2.rb

EDIT: Note that I do only few asynchronus huge submissions at the end of the program.

EDIT 2: I did one benchmark to see a little the performance, here the result to create that graph:
25.390000   1.060000  26.450000 ( 29.888871)